QGIS The grid line did not show in the layout
I'm currently working on a project using QGIS 3.38.2-Grenoble on windows 11. The data come from a DTM raster file that I exported to QGIS CRS: EPSG:3824 TWD97. The CRS for the grid I'm also using the same coordinate as the raster file.
When I set the interval to map units and the X=5000 and Y=5000, the grid line didn't show up.

But when I change the interval option to centermiters, and set the X and Y to 100,000, there's 0.000 showing up at the corner of the frame.


EPSG:3824 TWD97 is a Geographical CRS with the degree as unit of measure.
If your map's CRS is EPSG:3824 TWD97 and you specify the "Interval" parameter as "Map Units", then, as explained in the QGIS documentation, you need to specify the X and Y parameter in the map's unit, i.e. in degrees of longitude and latitude.
